# Entity comprising several fields and an image field. Post request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I can't send my request. I have several fields in my entity including an image field.Is it necessary to create an image entity or how to send only with a single entity that contains the field: description, name and image? Thank you very much for help

entity

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Shop{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String name_shop;

    private String description;

    private byte[] image;
}
```

Dto

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class ShopDto {

    private Integer id;

    @NotNull(message = "Le nom ne doit pas être null")
    @NotEmpty(message = "le nom ne doit pas être vide")
    private String name_shop;

    @NotNull(message = "La description ne doit pas être null")
    @NotEmpty(message = "La description ne doit pas être vide")
    private String description;

    private byte[] image;



    public static ShopDto fromEntity(Shop shop) {

        return ShopDto.builder()
                .id(shop.getId())
                .name_shop(shop.getName_shop())
                .description(shop.getDescription())
                .image(shop.getImage())
                .build();
    }

    public static Shop toEntity(ShopDto shop) {

        return Shop.builder()
                .id(shop.getId())
                .name_shop(shop.getName_shop())
                .description(shop.getDescription())
                .image(shop.getImage();
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/shop")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ShopController {

    private final ShopService shopService;

    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    @PostMapping(value = "/saveShop",consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Integer>save(
            @RequestPart("shopDto") ShopDto shopDto,
            ) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(shopService.save(shopDto));
    }
}
```

Repository

```
public interface ShopRepository extends JpaRepository<Shop, Integer> {
}
```

Service

```
public interface ShopService extends AbstractService<ShopDto>{
}
```

AbstractService

```
public interface AbstractService<T>{
    Integer save(T dto);
}
```

ServiceImpl

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ShopServiceImpl implements ShopService {
    private final ShopRepository shopRepository;
    private final ObjectsValidator<ShopDto> validator;

    @Override
    public Integer save(ShopDto dto) {
        validator.validate(dto);
        Shop shop = ShopDto.toEntity(dto);
        return shopRepository.save(shop).getId();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't send my request"?

Comment: You need put what error you got, but probably the error is related to the way you are trying to upload the image putting it in a `byte[]` instead in a `MultipartFile`

Comment: I added it but I still get the same error: 404 not found

Comment: how can I do it ? I added multipart in the controller. sorry i am learning springboot